# Google Maps API 2 for Android “Unfortunately, application has stopped."

Tags: android

I am android beginner, I follow a tutorial and try to show the google map using android. and I've also checked the other similar questions asked here, but am still unable to load a map :

## logcat:

```
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gmapsapp/com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity.servicesOK(MainActivity.java:40)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
12-29 14:16:53.025: E/AndroidRuntime(4499):     ... 11 more
```

## manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gmapsapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="mykey"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

## MainActivity

```
package com.example.gmapsapp;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

## activity_map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your application's AndroidManifest.xml file, and add the following declaration within the  element. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

This is a new requirement as of the updated google play services which is rev 13 i guess.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

There is no need for

```
<permission 
        android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

and this

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmapsapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Refer Specifying permission in the above link

Comment: “Unfortunately, application has stopped." problem is removed but map still not show on my device...

Comment: @user2387564 if it is a different problem post a new question and also post the stacktrace (logcat details of the crash)

Comment: @user2387564 comment section is no the best place to ask a new question. Start a new thread by posting one more question with relevant details

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="key" />
```

inside your application tag, in AndroidManifest.xml